# Is it possible to run multiple lines of Javascript code without entering any interactive shell?

Tags: javascript, shell, command-line, cmd

I am a newbie at programming so I would appreciate any help that can be provided! I am currently making a program that will be taking the attributes of another file (I don't know the terminology that well, so I apologize if it sounds confusing, it similar parsing the 'window' of Chrome) and saving it underneath the argument of `code`.I was wondering if it was possible to use Javascript code outside of an interface such as Node. I would like to know if there is a method to write multiple line code such as the following in Javascript while being outside of the interactive shell in order to use the argument I have:

```
var text= 'thisissomesortofstringwithwordsfromthefileinitnearthebegginingandwordsattheend';
var text2= text.split(/w(.+)/)[1]
var list = []
list.push(text)
```

This is where `var text` would be a string returned from parsing the file attributes (something like `var text = window.document.body`) and all of the above and possibly more code would be saved under `code`. If possible, I would appreciate if there was any method of running this code from a not isolated environment (not by using a file name, as that makes the argument unusable) or by using a command line command that could accept arguments. 
I would like to have a method that could be placed down such as `!node code` but my search turned up negative. Is there any such method or other means of reading Javascript that allows me to use external arguments? Thank you for your time and consideration with regards to my question, it means a lot to me!

Comment: So basically, you'd want to pass javascript code to node through the command line?

Comment: @MinusFour would appreciate if there was some method in which I could run Javascript from another source/file and still keep the destination paths, not just restricting myself to node or the command line if you have any ideas.